# Based on distance away from a coordinate, generate score. (Lower Distance Away => Higher Score)

Tags: javascript, math

here is my question:
Based on distance away from a coordinate, generate a score. The smaller the distance away, the higher the score would be. How could this be done? I'm new to JS and not very good a math so how would I make a function to do this?

1000 would be the highest score achievable and 0 would be the lowest score achievable. Marking the first person who answers this question.

An real life example is provided in the image. A game called GeoGuessr calculates a score from 0-5000 based on the distance away from a point. View image for refrence.

Thanks so much all.

[image]

Comment: My apologies if this question is in any way broad, but I tried to be as specific as I can!! thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are of course many possible ways to do it, but here is a suggestion: use a Gaussian formula like

```txt
score = 1000 * exp(-0.5 * (distance / sigma)^2)
```

where `sigma` is a positive parameter controlling the width of the Gaussian and `exp` is the exponential function (`Math.exp()` in JavaScript). This way, distance = 0 corresponds to the max score of 1000. The score decreases monotonically as distance increases, and asymptotically score = 0 as distance → ∞.

[image: Plot of Gaussian score]

Comment: my bad, but can you provide another example? What would I provide as exp? It's saying it doesn't exist as a function. Could you fill in this parameters and send it to me below. Thanks so much

Comment: Fair question! By "exp", I mean the exponential function or `Math.exp()` in JavaScript.

Comment: What do you think I should provide as the sigma? @Pascal Getreurer

Comment: The sigma parameter scales how wide the Gaussian is in the same units as the distance. I'd choose sigma to be a distance that's close enough to call "in the vicinity" but not "near". Or to put it quantitatively, at distance = sigma, the score is about 60% of the maximum [1000 * exp(-0.5) = 606.5].

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as the `gaussian formula` answers `edit-queue is full`. I just wanted to add that the `correct syntax for Javascript` for the `formula` is:

```
score = 1000 * Math.exp(-0.5 * (distance / sigma)**2)
```

Notice the

> **2 instead of the ^2. ^2 in javascript is a bitwise XOR expression.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Exponentiation

Answer (score 0):

If you want a linear decrease and strict point for zero score then you can use this formula:

```
MaxPoints - distance * MaxPoints / DistanceForZeroScore
```

You can add `Math.max(formula, 0)` if you don't want negative scores.

Distance between points (A,B) and (X,Y) can be calculated in many ways, but the most natural is [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance):

```
sqrt((A-X)^2+(B-Y)^2)
```

So the complete formula can be for example

```
Math.max(1000 - Math.sqrt((A-X)^2+(B-Y)^2) * 1000 / 3000, 0)
```

Comment: when the distance gets larger like from San Francisco to LA, the function returns with N/A. Any ideas? Thanks so much

Comment: @PaulMcBurney maybe something is over the limit at some point. Break down calculations into several steps and check which one is giving the wrong value.

Comment: You simply cannot even suggest Euclidean distance for two points on a sphere...